# Is $S = \{\alpha \in \mathbf{R}^3 \mid \alpha_1 + \alpha_2e^{-t} + \alpha_3 e^{-2t} \leq 1.1 \mbox{ for } t\geq 1\}$ affine

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

$$S = \{ \alpha \in \mathbf{R}^3 \mid \alpha_1 + \alpha_2e^{-t} +
\alpha_3 e^{-2t} \leq 1.1 \mbox{ for } t\geq 1\}$$

Is $S$ affine, and is it a polyhedron?

I thought it's basically a linear function in $\alpha$, thus affine. Since the linear function is characterized by $t$, as $t$ changes, there are many linear functions, thus a polyhedron? Is my reasoning correct, please?

Supplement:

Plotted @A.Γ's equation

[image]

Comment: A polyhedron is an intersection of a *finite* number of half-spaces. Compare with: $\alpha_1\cos t+\alpha_2\sin t\le 1$, $t\in[0,2\pi]$ is a unit disc (not a polyhedron), though for each $t$ it is a half-plane.

Comment: I plotted your equation. It's not affine, then why is it not a polyhedron? Is it because the number of half spaces not finite?

Comment: It is not likely to be a polyhedron because the normal vector $(1,e^{-t}, e^{-2t})$ moves along a space non-linear curve. Yes, finite number is important. Any convex closed set is an intersection of half-spaces.

Comment: For "Any convex closed set (doesn't have to be a polyhedron) is an intersection of half-spaces.", it doesn't matter whether the number is finite or not, right?

Comment: The number of half-spaces is determined by the number of exposed faces, it maybe whatever, but for polyhedrons they are finitely many. The set $S$ here is convex and closed.